# Change data Capture in a database - Manual Method

Tags: python, oracle, capture

Getting notified if there is a change in the historical data.

Our existing oracle database doesn't support CDC.Looking for other options to implement CDC

Let suppose I have a fact table A, which has the data from 1-jan-2019 to Current period. At any point of time the data in Jan/feb month should not change when I run the query as of today.

I am thinking of creating a table which has snapshot date which will capture data from fact A (like sum of orders or $ data)  weekly starting from 1-Jan-2019 to until present day.Thinking of this table as a log.

There should be other mechanism/table which will alert if there is change in the log table for a given snapshot date vs previous snapshot date.This is something, I am still thinking on how to design

my tools would be python and Oracle.Let me know if there is any better approach

Comment: What is "CDC"? I'm familiar with this being an abbreviation for "The Center For Disease Control" but I doubt that's what you mean here. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags and clarify this point. Thanks.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis,  CDC probably means [Change Data Capture](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm), a feature which is no longer supported in Oracle 12c and above.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle captures changes and write changes to the redo log files (and there are - in addition to the database itself - some products that use the redo log files), but, reading your question I guess you would want to look at materialized views

for Oracle 12c you have documentation for materialized views here 
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302

and materialized view logs here
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6003.htm#SQLRF01303